# Git - do not listen to commands in nested dirs

Tags: git, dotfiles

I've got a git repo in my home directory to keep track of some dotfiles.

An unpleasant side effect of that, no matter where I am now, it is considered a part of the `~` repo, and it's easy to mistakenly add files to it etc.

It is somehow possible, that the repo in `~/.git` listens to commands (`git add`, etc) ONLY if these commands are invoked directly in `~`, and otherwise it just pretends to not exist, i.e. `not a repository` is thrown? (For example, if I invoke `git add -A` in `~/Documents`)

Comment: IMO having your home directory as a git repo only makes sense when you've set up extensive `.gitignore` to ensure it only gets dirty when you want it to. Personally I'd shy away from that and put specific directories (and even files) under git control and symlink them as appropriate. In order to be able to give a better answer: can you explain how you *want* `~/Documents` for example to be handled? Do you want to track *some* files but not others? Only track files you explicitly add?

Comment: Some time ago, I finally decided to put a bunch of dot-files under Git control. To do that I made a Git repository that holds (a) a (python) script to install the dot-files; (b) a collection of said dot-files; (c) other useful scripts. This `.git` lives in my `~/scripts`. That way I don't have a `.git` in my home directory at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No this is not possible.

Another way, however, can be to use a non standard `.git` directory :

- rename your `.git/` directory to some other name (e.g : `.git-wont-know/`, or `.git-dotfiles/`)
- use `git --git-dir=~/.git-wont-know ...` when you want to interact with it ([link to docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt))

You can set an alias or a wrapper to use this specific git dir ; you can also set `GIT_DIR=~/.git-wont-know` if you want to pass this down to existing scripts.

---

[update] this turns off the "spot where the repo is located by looking for the `.git` directory" feature.

If you want to invoke git with this setup from a subdirectory (say : from `$HOME/.config/`), you may want to also specify that the worktree is your home directory :

```
git --git-dir=~/.git-wont-know --work-tree=~ ...

# or using environment variables :
GIT_DIR=~/.git-wont-know
GIT_WORK_TREE=~
```

Comment: That's probably `--git-dir` with two dashes, right? Nice suggestion, I like it.